# position: sticky flickers Safari iOS only

Tags: ios, safari, flicker

When there is an element with position: sticky, and user scrolls down on the page, the sticky element is a few pixels behind -being partially scrolled out of view, and eventually flickers back to the correct position when the scrolling is halted.

The same conditions as the linked issue above (Safari iOS only)